# Do I need SD card if I use tftpboot?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, petalinux

I am trying to boot a Zynq 7000 board using petalinux by tftpboot. Do I still need a SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD card is not mandatory. But you need a storage device to load FSBL, U-Boot, etc. It can be a QSPI flash, SD card, eMMC chip, ...
If your board has QSPI flash, then you can boot from it and use tftpboot without an SD card.

Comment: It seems Zynq 7000 has QSPI interface, is that what you mean?

Comment: May I ask why do I need another storage device, when I have stored all the files under the petalinux directory in my cpu?

Comment: @Creator Yes and there usually is a flash device connected to QSPI interface, which is used as primary boot device.

Comment: @Creator Zynq 7000 requires a storage device to run FSBL (first-stage bootloader) from. In addition, you will probably need U-Boot on that device to configure Ethernet and run tftpboot.

Comment: As per you answer, I am trying example 10 of the link,  https://xilinx.github.io/Embedded-Design-Tutorials/docs/2021.1/build/html/docs/Introduction/Zynq7000-EDT/7-linux-booting-debug.html  But I do not have the file u-boot-zynq-scr No idea why I do not have that file.